# Increase entropy pool by writing to /dev/random (macOS)?

Tags: macos, random, entropy

I know there's rng-tools for Linux, but haven't found a port for macOS, so I'm trying to do it manually. I understand you can write to /dev/random to fill the entropy pool (at least in Linux, probably same applies to macOS?). So what happens when you read from /dev/random after writing to it? Is it something like a fifo/lifo-buffer? Will the data read from /dev/random be a mix of system generated pseudo random numbers and what I fed it with? Can something be done so that /dev/random only supplies random numbers from an external source in macOS (I guess rng-tools will do this on Linux)?

Comment: would be interesting to know why you want to do this!  AFAIK macos always has hardware to ensure entropy is always available.  that said, on reasonable systems input data will be hashed with any existing state which will be used to seed a CSPRNG.  hence it should be impossible for to an attacker to control output of `/dev/random` via its input

Comment: I want to explore "true" randomness, if that's even a thing. I want to know for sure the numbers I get have never ever went through some kind of logic or algorithms. They should come from a random event in  nature, such as detecting radioactive decay from an isotope. It's more of an esoteric than scientific question for me. I guess I have to create random data from such external natural occuring event and store it in a file. Then create custom random functions to access the file, rather than use standard calls.

Comment: for what purpose?  any good PRNG (e.g. xoshiro256++ or pcg64) will give you uniform draws statistically indistinguishable from [IID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IID) uniform, and a CSPRNG will do so even in the presence of a determined attacker.  "real" or "true" randomness isn't so nice and will often come with significant non-uniformity (e.g. biases and auto-correlation) that normally need to be "cleaned up" before it's useful. if you want data, just get your computer to record some white noise (e.g. blow on the microphone) then take the least-significant bit of each sample